# How do I use FIND to manipulate cell text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is crazy. 
I have =FIND("Model=",A3)+6 which produces 36.
I have =FIND("|",A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6) which produces 40.
What does it take to get the results of 4?
=FIND("|",A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6)-FIND("Model=",A3)+6 produces 16.
I am using Office 2007 with all current updates. 
Logic says 40-36 should equal 4, but that is not what excel is producing.

This is my test string in A3
Year=1999|Make=Mercedes-Benz|Model=C230|Trim=Kompressor Sport Sedan 4-Door|Engine=2.3L 2295CC l4 GAS DOHC Supercharged

The formula that I am aiming for looks kinda like this:
=MID(A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6,FIND("|",A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6)-FIND("Model=",A3)+6)

This should return the results of C230 from above text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parenthesize in the '+6' before subtraction takes place, so change:

```
=FIND("|",A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6)-FIND("Model=",A3)+6
```

to:

```
=FIND("|",A3,FIND("Model=",A3)+6)-(FIND("Model=",A3)+6)
```

so it subtracts the entire sum, not just the first part of the sum.

It's clearer looking at a trivial example - you wanted something like:

```
3 - (1 + 2) = 0
```

but instead were doing:

```
3 - 1 + 2 = 4
```